# Python multiprocessing module, Windows, spawn new console window with the creation of a new process

Tags: python, windows, console, multiprocessing

I've done some research on this and found somewhat similar questions but none answer what I'm really looking for. I understand how to create and use processes with the `multiprocessing` module. But when I create a new process, I would like to spawn a new console window just for the use of that process, for printing and so on, so that the child processes don't share the parent process's console window. Is there a way of doing that with the `multiprocessing` module?

Comment: I have no idea how to do that. I'm curious though why you would need a new console window for a child process.  Seems a rather odd thing to be doing with the multiprocessing module.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you're going to spawn a new console window, then you're starting a new Windows console process as well as the new python process running inside it.

So the short (and unhelpful) answer would be that `multiprocessing` won't do this as it only spawns python processes.

However, I can see two ways around this;

- You use `multiprocessing` and each process creates a `Tkinter` window displaying the text you desire. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13318742/python-logging-to-tkinter-text-widget) question has an example for sending `logging` output to a `Tkinter` window. I'm suggesting `Tkinter` as it already comes with python, you could use `PyQt`, `wxWidgets` etc.
- You use [`subprocess`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html) to spawn an entirely separate and new python process (or console window + process). Note that you won't be able to `.join()` or share thread states easily this way. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11712629/opening-a-python-thread-in-a-new-console-window) question has an example of how to create a new python thread and window.

Comment: OK thank you! Very concise. I guess I'll use the GUI solution as my application needs child processes to share data easily.

Comment: Suppose you spawn new console windows from the the parent process (`os.system("start cmd.exe"`)). Is there a way to specify and assign the output stream of select children processes to select console windows?