# Logging output of TCL script into Tkinter text widget

Tags: python, python-2.7, logging, tkinter, tcl

I have done 2 separate things and now I want to join the two.
I am using command prompt on Windows 8

1. I have a TCL file that I can run from python. It gives all the outputs on command prompt. I use this command to run the TCL

   os.system(r'vivado -mode tcl -source location/my_tcl.tcl')

full code:

```
import Tkinter as tk
import os
import time

my_gui = tk.Tk()
mvar = tk.StringVar()

def my_hello():
    chk = mvar.get()
    if chk == '1':
        os.system(r'vivado -mode tcl -source path/my_tcl.tcl')
        f = open('input.txt', 'r')
        a = f.readline().rstrip('\n')
        if a == 'Passed':
            mlabel = tk.Label(my_gui,text = 'Test Passed', fg = 'black', bg = 'green',width = 10).place(x=200,y=10)
        else:
            mlabel = tk.Label(my_gui,text = 'Test Failed', fg = 'black', bg = 'red',width = 10).place(x=200,y=10)
        f.close
    else:
        mlabel = tk.Label(my_gui,text = 'No Test Run', fg = 'black', bg = 'yellow',width = 10).place(x=200,y=10)

my_gui.geometry('300x300+200+200')
my_gui.title('Test')

mbutton = tk.Button(my_gui,text = 'Run Tests!',command = my_hello).place(x=150,y=280,anchor= 'center')

check1 = tk.Checkbutton(my_gui,text = 'DDR Test',state = 'active', variable = mvar).place(x=10,y=10)
mvar.set('0')


my_gui.mainloop()
```

2. I have implemented simple logging on python following solutions from this thread: [Python Logging to Tkinter Text Widget](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13318742/python-logging-to-tkinter-text-widget)

full code: https://gist.github.com/bitsgalore/901d0abe4b874b483df3ddc4168754aa

Now I want to combine the two parts but logging require some sort of string input in order to store and display log. while output of TCL appears on command prompt. What i want to achieve is that all that appears on command prompt can be visible on my Tkinter text widget.

Is there a way I can do this?
Regards

Comment: show some of the code , then we can tell something

Comment: @AkshayKathpal I have added the code but as I said, they are 2 different tasks and I am not sure how to join them

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a somewhat static approach.
You can use the `subprocess` module, which allows you to capture the process' output, and then display it in a `tkinter.Text` widget.

```
import subprocess

def run_process():
    path = "script_with_some_output"
    p = subprocess.run(path, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)

    return p.stdout
```

Now, you can call `run_process()` to execute your process, and get its output as a sequence of bytes.
You can easily log that into a `Text` widget, by calling `text.insert(tk.END, run_process())`.

Here is a short example demonstrating this:

```
import tkinter as tk
import sys
import subprocess

def run_process():
    path = r"path/to/script"
    p = subprocess.run("python"+path, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
    return p.stdout

root = tk.Tk()
log = tk.Text(root)
b = tk.Button(root, text="Run stuff", command=lambda: log.insert(tk.END, run_process()))

log.pack()
b.pack()    

root.mainloop()
```

This script will run the script located at the given path, and display its output in the text widget.

Comment: I have already run a python script and captured it's stdout to the text widget but in some other way. I will try this method as well and get back to you. still i am not sure if this will work for my TCL script.

Comment: I ended up doing it a very different way but your solution was good too. Only thing missing is that it cannot display in parallel. It display complete output once the whole script completes

Comment: @MohsinShafiq Yes, I tried and fiddled a while with file descriptors in order to redirect `stdout` to the widget in real time, but I couldn't find any solution... how did you end up doing it? Would you mind posting it as an answer?

Comment: The script that i was running already making a log for all the output into a .log file.
I used solution provided here: https://gist.github.com/bitsgalore/901d0abe4b874b483df3ddc4168754aa
This code makes a separate thread to update contents of text widget in run time.
I added another thread which calls my script. script was creating a text file. So the other thread was responsible of reading the .log file and putting it line by line into the text widget.
run the code first and make changes in order to make it according to your need